# how can i create a function to read the numbers that the user inserts into an array in c?

Tags: c, function, average

I am new to programing.

I'm doing an exercise witch the user inserts numbers in an array and the program prints the average of those numbers.

But part of the exercise is making the numbers that the user inserts using a function, and thats where i'm struggling.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main() {

    int n = 10, i, array1[10];
    float sum = 0.0, average;

    printf("insert 10 numbers\n");

   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("insert digit no%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
        sum += array1[i];
    }
  average = sum / n;
    printf("average = %.2f", average);
    return 0;
    }
```

all the help is much apreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean? You want random numbers from function?

Comment: Do you want to move user input code section into a function? Is that it?

Comment: @RohanKumar yes that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move user input and average calculation into separate methods. It should be done something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Takes an array and get input for N items specified 
 */ 
void getUserInputForArray(int array[], int N) {
    printf("insert %d numbers\n", N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        printf("insert digit no %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}

/*
 * Calculate average for a given array of size N
 */ 
float getAverage(int array[], int N) {
    // Initialize sum to 0
    float sum = 0.0f;
    // Iterate through array adding values to sum
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        sum += array[i];

    // Calculate average 
    return sum / N;
}

int main() {
    int n = 10, array1[10];
    // Pass array to method, since arrays in C are passed by pointers.
    // So Even if you modify it in method it would get reflected in 
    // main's array1 too
    getUserInputForArray(array1, n);

    // Calculate Average by delegating average calculation to getAverage(...) method
    float average = getAverage(array1, n);

    printf("average = %.2f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much, i only wanted the user input and since i´'m a beginner, your method is a bit confusing to me XD.

Comment: I'm really sorry, let me add some explanation.

Comment: Hi, Could you please review my update and see if it's less confusing than before? Feel free to ask for explanation for any part that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small program to show you how functions work:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void foo(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

size_t bar(int array[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += array[i];

    return (sum);
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[3] = {0};
    int sum;

    foo(array, 3);
    sum = bar(array, 3);

    printf("array sum = %d\n", sum);

    return (0);
}
```

`foo` and `bar` are two functions, they both have a return type on the left side, a name (foo/bar), some parameters in the parentheses, and their body declaration between braces.

When you call a function from your main, you'll have to call it with its required parameters. In my exemple, both functions need an integer array, and an integer value as parameters. That's why we called it this way from the main: `foo(array, 3);` and `bar(array, 3)`.

When we call a function, the given parameters are copied into memory so you can work with those params into the function body as if they were variables.

Some functions have a return type different than `void`. Those functions are able to (and must) return a value of the return type with the `return` statement. Those values can be used, assigned etc, as you can see with the instruction `sum = bar(array, 3);`

Even the `main` is a function !